# bool keep returning true even tho value "NO"

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c++

i want to validate ssl pinning if values on bundle is `YES` and skip validation if the values is `NO`.

and i make this line of code for getting the value from main bundle

```
  bool enablePinning = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"SSL_PINNING_ENABLED"];
```

the problem is `enablePinning` keep returning empty bool, even tho when i log `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"SSL_PINNING_ENABLED"];` the value is valid

[image: SSL_PINNING_ENABLED value]

Comment: Your english is a little hard to understand. What is an _empty bool? What do you mean by "NSLog to enablePinning"? Could you please *remove* anything unnecessary, keeping just the calls that are interesting, and maybe in the comments add what is the output and what do you expect instead?

Comment: sorry i think im not explain the problem and what im expecting, i hope the edit make it little bit clearer @AndreasOetjen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BOOL enablePinning = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"SSL_PINNING_ENABLED"]
                                             boolValue];
```

`bool` and `BOOL` are not the same thing. In ObjC, you want `BOOL` here. The return value of `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` is an NSNumber, which you then need to unwrap with `-boolValue`.